# Personal & work Google Calendar together?

Tags: google-calendar

- I have my personal Google Calendar and I can access it from my Android phone.
- I have my company's Google Calendar

and I want to merge these two together but we share our company's Calendar inside the company, so I want to make sure that nobody can read my personal Calendar.

Is that possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you access both Calendars from within your normal Google Calendar on the web?

Assuming your company has shared out their calendar, you should be able to add that calendar as an additional calendar subscription on your personal Google Calendar. In your calendar view on the web, to the left of the calendar view, you should see a list of "My Calendars" with your main personal calendar in it, then under that "Other Calendars" which will include the company calendar.

To share out the company calendar (presuming you have permission to do this), log into the company calendar account, go to Settings -> Calendar Settings, click the Calendars tab and then click either "Share this calendar" or "Shared: Edit settings" and make sure that your personal account has at leats got permission to "See all event details" then click the calendar's name and you should see the the calendar addresses. Pick the ICAL address and copy the link.

Now log into your personal calendar and under "Other Calendars" click Add-> Add by URL, and paste the address you just copied into that box.

Once you have both calendars appearing for the one account on the web, then both should just show up on your Android phone, with the appointments coloured for which calendar they're in.

Comment: I am able to view my company's calendar inside my personal one on web but android. There is just my personal one.

Comment: @Radek What version of Android is your phone running, I seem to remember only being able to get one calendar on my old Android 1.5 phone, now I'm running 2.1 they all come down. Might be best to take this over to http://android.stackexchange.com as I think it's probably an Android problem rather than a web app one.